# Angular 2 with Watson Conversation (CHATBOT) - How to Implement?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

I'm currently developing an Ionic Framework Chat using Watson Conversation from IBM Bluemix Watson's Services, but unfortunately i'm going through a hard time on how can I implement Watson Conversation services into my App. Ionic uses Angular, although I've made a similar application using Android Studio in which is pretty easy to use Watson Services, I really have no idea on how to implement on Angular, I tried searching on Internet but was unable to find good examples. Have anyone ever implemented a Chat using Angular and Watson Conversation services? If so, could you please provide a line of code or a documentation that can assist me in this process?

Best Regards,

Fabio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some APIs do not allow Frontend clients request hence you have to create a backend for your angular app and make the api calls from your backend. In your case, you can create a simple node backend that responses to your angular2 app's requests then make api calls to IBM Watson and responses with data from IBM Watson.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but try here: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/323117/call-bluemix-watson-service-from-angularjs-applica.html

Comment: Was looking for something more like this https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/?node#send_message but in Angular instead of Node